# Cannot load fl.transitions.Tween and other similar in project

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I am using flex sdk 4.5 to develop my project. I need to use the generic Tweening packages in As3 but when I import these packages

```
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*;
```

while compilation the sdk tell, it cannot find the upper packages. Any idea why, or how to import them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about native Tween class and switch to TweenLite / TweenMax.
It's amazing and it will change the way you work. It's one of the best tweening library out there :)

http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the `spark.effects.animation.Animation` object to have similar functionality to Tween, or `spark.effects.Animate` to add effects to components.

Here is a link with more detailed information:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_effects_pt1.html

Have great day!

Comment: can I use this with plain AS3 code, not mxml syntax? I just need simple fade in/ fade out effect.

Comment: Sure you can. MXML is just a form short-hand Action Script.